# How to send canvas image to database on form submit in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas

I'm creating an app in Rails where users are able to draw on an html5 canvas with JavaScript. With JavaScript, I've been able to convert the canvas to an image so the user can easily right click the canvas and save the image:

```
var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function(){
     ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    };
    img.src = window.mapImgUrl;
```

However, the problem is that the canvas lives on a form. I want the image result to somehow get added to the database so I can show previous drawings on other views of the app. I set up CarrierWave and AWS for image uploads, but I can't figure out a way to reconfigure the settings to treat the canvas images as uploads on submitting the form. Is this something that will have to involve AJAX or base64? Or is there some way to make use of CarrierWave for this?

Comment: What are you doing to get the canvas as image?

Comment: I'm using the javascript drawImage method on the canvas, so the user can right click the canvas after drawing on it and it saves as a PNG file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you've to do is to send the image as base-64 to the server, then re-use the base64 source when needed.

```
var imgbuffer = canvas.toDataURL(); // canvas, not ctx
```

Otherwise it may not work, as the image format bytes are interpreted and may be replaced by other characters. That's why base-64 is best.